# replace text with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file with 2 column. the frist containing a list of codes (ex. GRT986E) or in some other cases I have an object consisting of 2 parts divided by a low dash (ex. TRY546 _ TRE578). Sometimes between objects there are one or more empty lines. For some of these objects in the second column there is an associated variable. The file is like this:

```
QR846OI bbbbbbbbb

PO3R56  ddddddd
UJ6Y68 eeeeeee


YU654R

PL92WS
GH654Y _ HUY765R tttttt
```

I want to take the second column and replace only the text with "yes" and I want separated the first and second column with ",".
The output.txt will be like this:

```
QR846OI,yes

PO3R56,yes
UJ6Y68,yes


YU654R

PL92WS
GH654Y _ HUY765R,yes
```

I use this command line:

```
awk -F , '{ if ($2 != " ") $2="yes";}1' OFS=, good_interactors.txt > output.txt
```

but it doesn't work very well.

Comment: Why shouldn't `tttttt` be replaced by `yes`, too?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, also "tttttt" must be replaced

Comment: I'm noticing that you have four active questions, but that you have not accepted any answers on any of those questions.  Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  You may also want to take [the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the spaces around the underscore using `sed` and optionally revert it afterwards. That makes it much easier for `awk`:

```bsh
awk '{OFS=","}NF==2{$2="yes"}1' <(sed 's/ _ /_/g' file) \
| sed 's/_/ _ /g' # <- this part is optional
```

Output:

```
QR846OI,yes

PO3R56,yes
UJ6Y68,yes


YU654R

PL92WS
GH654Y _ HUY765R,yes
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 awk 'NF>1 {$NF="yes" ; print ; } NF <= 1 { print }' file | sed 's/ yes/,yes/'
```

- this filter on `NF` (number of field).
- `sed` command to delete space
- some people use `1` instead of `print`

  ```
  awk 'NF>1 {$NF="yes" ; }1' file | sed 's/ yes/,yes/'
  ```

Comment: Not in the example, but this would not work as intended for lines having only  `GH654Y _ HUY765R`.

Answer (score 0):

Posixly awk :

```
awk -v repl=",yes" '
  BEGIN {
    s = "[[:space:]]"; S = "[^[:space:]]"
    pat = sprintf("%s+%s+%s*$", s, S, s)
  }
  NF>1 && sub(pat, repl) || 1' file
```